# Sorting an array of objects with lodash: not working

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array that looks like this one (it has more objects, but the structure is the same):

```
[
  {
      especiality: "surgery",
      users: [
          {
              id: "182",
              country: "Colombia",
              province: "Bogota",
              telephone: "211112212",
              neighbourhood: "La Santa"
              region: "South",
          },
          {
            id: "182",
            country: "Venezuela",
            province: "Caracas",
            telephone: "322323333",
            region: "North",
        },
        {
          id: "183",
          country: "Brasil",
          telephone: "23232333",
          neighbourhood: "Santos"
          region: "South",
      },
      ]
  },
```

I want the addresses, if the ID is the same, to compose one single array (I need to map these elements). The outlook should look like this one:

```
user: [{id: 182, locations[(if they exist)               
              country: "Colombia",
              province: "Bogota",
              telephone: "211112212",
              neighbourhood: "La Santa"
              region: "South"], [country: "Venezuela",
            province: "Caracas",
            telephone: "322323333",
            region: "North"],}]
```

I´m currently trying this, but it´s not working at all:

```
getGroups = test => {
  _.chain(test)
  .groupBy("id")
  .toPairs()
  .map(item => _.zipObject(["id", "country", "province", "neighbourhood", "region"], item))
  .value();
  return test
  }
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I account for values that may not be available in all objects?

Comment: why do you have an outer array? are there more items with `users`? do you want to rouo all others as well?

Comment: The outer array is the way the data structure I´m dealing with is structured. Yes, there are more items with users, but they all share the same structure

Answer (score 1):

After grouping the items by the `id`, map the groups, and create an object with the `id`, and the items of the group as `locations`. Map the locations, and use `_.omit()` to remove the `id` from them.

I'm not sure about how you want to handle the outer array. I've used `_.flatMap()` to get a single array of users, but there's a commented option if you need to maintain the original structure.

```js
getGroups = test =>
  _(test)
  .groupBy("id")
  .map((locations, id) => ({
    id,
    locations: _.map(locations, l => _.omit(l, 'id'))
  }))
  .value();

const data = [{"especiality":"surgery","users":[{"id":"182","country":"Colombia","province":"Bogota","telephone":"211112212","neighbourhood":"La Santa","region":"South"},{"id":"182","country":"Venezuela","province":"Caracas","telephone":"322323333","region":"North"},{"id":"183","country":"Brasil","telephone":"23232333","neighbourhood":"Santos","region":"South"}]}];

const result = _.flatMap(data, ({ users }) => getGroups(users));

/** maintains the original structure
const result = _.map(data, ({ users, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  users: getGroups(users)
}));
**/

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```